# Generating a pdf document for every row

Tags: r

I am trying to generate .pdf documents for each row, then store the pdf documents by their row names. Here is the sample data:

```
canada <- c(100, 80, 100, 100, 20)
korea <- c(100, 80, 100, 26, 65)
brazil <- c(100, 90, 100, 30, 30)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, brazil)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "orange", "banana", "grape", "kiwi")
fruit

price <- function(val){

  val <- tolower(val)
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)
  score.min <- c(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]

  cat(paste0("In ", nation, " cheapest fruit costs ", score.min, " cents."))

}
```

So, for the output, I would end up with three pdf documents: Canada, Korea, and Brazil. And, each pdf document would contain a sentence, "In *nation*, cheapest fruit costs *x* cents."

I have thus far tried rmarkdown, but I cannot figure out a way to automate the process of creating new pdf's by their row names. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot the single line using the pdf graphics driver.  Below `price` is as defined in the question. No intermediate files are produced and no packages are used.  This should be ok for up to a page of text which is more than enough given that your problem only involves a single line per file.

```
write_lines_pdf <- function(x, file = "pdffile", ...) {
    if (!grepl("\\.pdf$", file)) file <- paste0(file, ".pdf") # append .pdf if not present
    pdf(file)
    plot.new()
    text(x = 0, y = 1, labels = paste(x, collapse = "\n"), adj = c(0, 1), ...)   
    dev.off()
}

for(nm in rownames(fruit)) write_lines_pdf(capture.output(price(nm)), nm)
```

Another example using the built-in vector `month.name`:

```
write_lines_pdf(month.name)
```

Alternately consider using `gplots::textplot` with appropriate arguments in place of `plot.new(); text(...)` .

If the input strings flow off the side of the page try `strwrap` to wrap the text around to following lines or  use the `cex` graphics parameter to make the text smaller.  If `x` is the input text then:

```
write_lines_pdf(strwrap(x, 50)) # wrap at column 50

write_lines_pdf(x, cex = 0.7) # make text smaller
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This works well for parts of my script! I have another question. For long sentences, the texts run out of bounds instead of creating a new line. What would be the command I should be using to tell R to create a new line once a word is about to run out of bound?

Comment: If `x` is your input string use `write_lines_pdf(strwrap(x, 50))` to wrap it to 50 characters or `write_lines_pdf(x, cex = 0.5)` to make the text smaller.  Vary 50 or 0.5 as needed.  `gplots::textplot` will automatically set `cex` if you want to use that.

Comment: Still trying to figure it out, but thank you so much for providing me with the scaffolding. I am learning as we speak.

Comment: Is there an alternative to `strwrap`? I can't bypass the Error in width - nchar(initial, type = "w") :  non-numeric argument to binary operator. I want to use something like the `strwrap` function because my document is in paragraphs.

Comment: You will need to provide a reproducible example of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had to edit `price` a bit by removing the `cat`

```
price <- function(val){

  val <- tolower(val)
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)
  score.min <- c(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]

  paste0("In ", nation, " cheapest fruit costs ", score.min, " cents.")

}

library(rmarkdown)

for (x in rownames(fruit)) {
  rmdfile = paste0(x,".Rmd")
  cat(price(x), file=rmdfile)
  render(input = rmdfile, output_format = "pdf_document")
}
```